# How to index multi-dimensional array with an array that is row-dependent?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I've got a manual way to reference the numpy array, but can't figure out how to do it in a numpy-like manner.

I am looking for a numpy-like equivalent of the following line:

```
np.array([arr[0,index[0]], arr[1,index[1]], arr[2,index[2]]]).reshape(3,1)
```

Here is the code (simplified to pinpoint the issue):

```
arr = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
index = np.array([2,0,1])
print(arr)
result = np.array([arr[0,index[0]], arr[1,index[1]], arr[2,index[2]]]).reshape(3,1)
print(result)
```

it produces the following:

```
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]
[[2]
 [3]
 [7]]
```

I am looking for numpy-style code to achieve what the line

```
np.array([arr[0,index[0]], arr[1,index[1]], arr[2,index[2]]]).reshape(3,1)
```

is doing here, for example:

```
arr[:,index[:]]
```

Obviously, this doesn't work correctly, because index[:] denotes the whole row instead of picking just one corresponding value.

This must be very simple, I am just somehow stuck on it. Can't figure out how to do it without a long line that manually brings every index for every row. In my case I have thousands of rows and thousands of columns, so definitely can't use the manual way.

Comment: @Divakar I've gone through the referenced posts, and came up with the answer to my question: arr[[0,1,2],index] does exactly what I need. But I still can't understand how it works, why it does what it does. I am new to numpy and would greatly appreciate some help. More specifically, how exactly numpy is treating 2 totally different instructions which look very similar: 1) arr[0:3,index] and 2) arr[[0,1,2],index]

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way to achieve what you are going for is by direct indexing:

```
arr = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
index = np.array([2,0,1])
result = arr[range(index.shape[0]), index].reshape(index.shape[0], 1)
```

To answer your comment, the reason why slices don't produce the same results, i.e. code like this

```
arr[0:index.shape[0], index]
```

is due to the fact that the `0:index.shape[0]` is a slice, not a list of indices to pick. Whenever you use slices as index, it understands as *all rows in range* or *all columns in range*. However if you *list* the indices instead (via lists or arrays) it will only pick the elements from the list.

There are many more tricks with NumPy indexing, their documentation is always a good source of information: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html.

Answer (score 1):

With a row selection of `[0,1,2]` rows and `[2,0,1]` columns there two ways of selecting items:

```
block
items [2,0,1] from each of the rows [0,1,2]

paired
items [0,2], [1,0], [2,1]
```

In MATLAB if you index `arr([0,1,2],[2,0,1])` you get the block.  In `numpy` indexing `arr[[0,1,2],[2,0,1]]` does the paired indexing that you want.

To get the block in `numpy` you can do `arr[:, [2,0,1]]` or `arr[[[0],[1],[2]], [2,0,1]]`.

This second case actually makes a (3,1) array that broadcasts with a (3,) to create a (3,3) set of index pairs.  To understand `advanced indexing` with more than one list or array, you need to understand broadcasting.

In the case of 1d arrays/lists that match in size the broadcasting is trivial - just pair them up:

```
arr([0,1,2],[2,0,1])
arr[0,2], arr[1,0], arr[2,1]
```